# enable to call the webhook in docker image

Tags: docker, gitlab, containers, webhooks, azure-web-app-service

1. I have a hosted container web app on azure which is working. but for
   CI with the Gitlab container registry I need to call the webhook url
   in gitlab-ci.yaml file.
2. when I called the *webhook* url with postman with POST request it's pulling the latest image for registry. when I made same request
   in  gitlab-ci.yaml file using curl it's showing an error Access is
   denied due to invalid credentials.

   ```
   $ curl -d -X POST https://$acr-image:SOME_SECRET_KEY@acr-image.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook
   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
   <title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
   <style type="text/css">
   ```